# Firebase user agent disclosure

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Do I need to disclose firebase user agent data in Google play data safety section and if yes in which category and how I am only using firestore In my application and not taking any inputs from user.

Comment: Please try to better explain your question / questions

Comment: Also to improve your question, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)